# Using custom annotations to generate biolerplate code

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, jax-rs

Folks,
I am about to write a ton of J2EE/JAX-RS code where practically all public methods will do the following:

- Look for the presence of a security token in the request header.
- Call a utility to make sure the token is valid.
- If not valid, return an error response (or inject a null token)
- If valid, do some stuff, which might involve introspecting the token
- In most cases, return an updated token in response headers.

I'd love to be able to use annotations to abstract out this piece. I am imagining something like the following on the method:

```
@RequireToken( returnRenewed=true )
@POST
@Path( "/some/path" )
public Result myMethod( ... )
{
    @InjectedToken
    final Token securityToken;
    ...
}
```

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using spring security for those actions? You might implement your own authentication filters.

If not spring security, maybe AOP and "before" or "around advice"s ?

Comment: Hi Mich, thanks for your response. I am squarely in the J2EE/EJB3 camp, so I have not considered Spring security. If AOP is more generic, I'd be happy to check it out. Is there a good reference you can point me to?

Comment: You can use AOP from Spring AOP module which is very easy to use. If you're using J2EE/EJB3 it wont be a problem. Spring framework is very modular, so you can use only a part of it. What is more in case of spring technologies always documentation is the best source of info. AOP: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html Around advice part: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice

Comment: If you'd like not to use anything connected with spring, you'd have to read about aspectj.

Comment: Is AspectJ what is typically used to do runtime code instrumentation based on annotations? I'd love to know, for example, how does the EJB framework or the JAX-RS do this to modify servlet/EJB code at runtime to do code injection, etc?

Comment: Im not expert in this area but I think some libraries uses reflections, others manipulation on bytecode usign cglib2.